# Using subform for report options

Tags: ms-access, vba

Pretty new at this.  I have a main form with a list box of job numbers and a subform for the different reports.  I want to be able to select a job name and then double click the report name to preview it but it gives me an error.  It doesn't seem to recognize my selected job name from the list box.  Error message is *"Compile Error: Method or Data Member Not Found".* See image.

[image: Image Of Form View]

Here is the code i'm using which is on the Double Click event on the text box in the subform.

```
Private Sub ReportName_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)

Dim strFilter As String
If IsNull(Me.lstJobName) Then
    MsgBox "You Must Select A Job"
    Me.lstJobName.SetFocus
Exit Sub
End If

strFilter = "JobName = '" & Me.lstJobName & "'"
DoCmd.OpenReport ReportName.Value, acViewPreview, , strFilter

End Sub
```

Trying to figure this out step by step so just need the report to preview for now.  Later I will want to check off the reports that I need printed then just click a button to print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is behind the subform therefore the Me. qualifier is alias for the subform and code is looking for the listbox on the subform but it is actually on the main form.

`strFilter = "JobName = '" & Me.Parent.lstJobName & "'"`

Comment: That worked perfectly.  I was missing "parent" in my code.  It would have taken me a long time to figure that out.  Thank you!